# Pass QString variable between classes in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I am new to Qt and working on my first project. I need to declare the value of a `QString` in a login window and then read the value from the dialog screen which loads after login.

My current code is:

```
Login.h

public:
QString store;

Login.cpp

      QSqlQueryModel * storeList=new QSqlQueryModel();

      QSqlQuery* q=new QSqlQuery(theDB);


      q->prepare("Select Store from Users where Username='"+username+"'");

      q->exec();
      userList->setQuery(*q);
      q->first();
      store = q->value(0).toString();


      qDebug()<<store;
```

This works fine at this point and the value for store is logged in the console.

However whenever i try and access this variable in merchant.cpp the string is empty and "" is logged.

```
merchant.cpp

Login conn;
qDebug()<<conn.store;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated and I apologise if this is a stupid question

Comment: Is the code, shown in `Login.cpp`, written in `Login` constructor?

Comment: The code as posted isn't even close to compiling or running.  It needs to be expanded.